# Remove zero's from gridview cell when binding to a datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is populated using a stored procedure within SQL Server 2012. I am using VS 2013 VB.net.

The following code runs on page load which creates the gridview using a class

```
Dim mReport As New MorningReport

Dim mReports As New List(Of MorningReport)
mReports = mReport.morningReportGridview

GridMorningReport.DataSource = mReports
GridMorningReport.DataBind()
```

In the aspx page I use template fields with `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`

I have four columns and the last one has a few zeros in it (see below) and these values will always be zeros.

[image]

I want to replace the zeros with nothing so I tried to use the following which is triggered after the databind above.

```
Public Sub removeZeros()

    Dim row As GridViewRow

    For Each row In GridMorningReport.Rows
        If row.Cells(3).Text = "0" Then
            row.Cells(3).Text = ""
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This does nothing, however if I change the 0 to "" and the "" to "7" then all the cells change to 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted it, had an epiphany!!

Inside each cell is a label so I used FindControl

```
 Public Sub removeZeros()

    Dim row As GridViewRow

    For Each row In GridMorningReport.Rows
        If CType(row.Cells(3).FindControl("lblThermsday"), Label).Text = "0" Then
            CType(row.Cells(3).FindControl("lblThermsday"), Label).Text = ""
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```